# Disable/remove Let's Encrypt?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I followed this tutorial to enable Let's Encrypt on my server, however I now want to remove/disable it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

To remove letsencrypt as installed by that link

```
rm -rf /opt/letsencrypt
```

To remove any certs and other letsencrypt stuff

```
rm -ft /etc/letsencrpt
```

then disable the server/vhost using the certs and restart apache.